# ShipStation Shipping Label creation is not working Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, php, database, shipping, shipping-methods

We upgrade the Magento 2.2 to 2.4.2 .  We have configure the ShipStation as shipping. But we are not able to create shipping label. We are stuck in Add to products to packege popup. Save button doing nothing.
Please find the attachment.

Thanks [image]